# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (JSONP request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm making an AJAX request like this:

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&callback=?', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

But I get an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Not sure how to fix this given I don't control the server response. Any thoughts?

Comment: is jquery added to ur project?

Comment: I think you not added jquery. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try using [fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)

```
fetch('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&callback=?')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
```